# Как сделать, чтобы один div выделялся, а все остальное затемнялось?

Tags: css, jquery

На сайте есть определенная область(div), нужно по нажатию кнопки оставить эту область яркой, а все остальное сделать темнее. Как это можно реализовать?
Гугл честно не дал ответов, про дарк мод знаю, но это не то.
Когда-то видела на сайте онлайн-кинотеатра что-то подобное, там "экран" оставался, а все остальное затемнялось. Извините, если формулировка вопроса кривая и заранее спасибо за ответы!

UPD моя ошибка, что не приложила код, исправляю

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bg-container"></div> <!-- это параллакс фон -->
<div class="content-wrapper">
  <div id="page1"></div>
  <div id="page2" class="hide"><!-- потом с помощью jquery animate класс меняется -->
    <div class="flipbook-viewport">
                <div class="container">
                  <div class="player"></div>
                  <div class="flipbook"> <!-- это книга реализованная на turn.js --></div>
                  </div>
                  </div>
  
  </div>



</div>
```

css и js там очень много, поэтому не стала прикладывать, надеюсь примерная структура поможет

Comment: Опиши вопрос подробнее... Покажи верстку...

Comment: Делаете темную полупрозрачную подложку и z-index-ом располагаете ее между вашим дивом и всем остальным сайтом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Набросал пример на plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/HbAmiXHZjcPGejDnMo8y)

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Bootstrap, from Twitter</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />
    <!-- Le styles -->
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css" data-semver="4.1.1" rel="stylesheet" href="<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="4.1.3" rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <style>
      body {
        padding-top: 60px;
      }
      @media (max-width: 979px) {

        /* Remove any padding from the body */
        body {
          padding-top: 0;
        }
      }
    </style>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="images/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="images/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png" />
    <script data-require="jquery" data-semver="3.2.1" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.2.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="bootstrap" data-semver="4.1.3" src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-between">
    <header>
      <div>
        Хедер
      </div>
    </header>
    <div class="container-fluid position-relative d-flex">
      <div class="d-flex flex-row">
        <div class="p-2">Серота то какая..</div>
        <div class="p-2">Серота</div>
        <div class="p-2">Серота</div>
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex flex-row-reverse">
        <div class="p-2 d-flex w-10">Серота</div>
        <div id="make-me-shine" class="p-2 d-flex flex-column position-relative">
          <div>
            <h2>Отличная Яркая область :)</h2>
            <div>
              Нужно больше текста
              Нужно больше текста
              Нужно больше текста
              Нужно больше текста
              Нужно больше текста
              Нужно больше текста
              Нужно больше текста
            </div>

            <img src="https://picsum.photos/425?image=237"/>
          </div>
          <input class="btn btn-primary" style="max-width: 425px" type="button" value="ТЫЦ!" onClick="toggleBackdrop()"/>
        </div>
        <div class="p-2  d-flex w-70">Серота</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <footer>
      <div>Футер</div>
    </footer>
  </body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.backdrop body:before {
  content: ' ';
  background: #ccc;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top:0;
  opacity: 0.5;
  display: block;
  z-index:10;
}

.backdrop .shine-on-you-crazy-diamond {
  z-index: 20;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: #fff;
}

footer, header {
  height: 80px;
  background: #acc;
}
```

JS:

```
function toggleBackdrop() {
  if (document.getElementById('make-me-shine').classList.contains('shine-on-you-crazy-diamond')) {
    document.querySelector('html').classList.remove('position-relative', 'backdrop');
    document.getElementById('make-me-shine').classList.remove('shine-on-you-crazy-diamond');
  } else {
      document.querySelector('html').classList.add('position-relative', 'backdrop');
      document.getElementById('make-me-shine').classList.add('shine-on-you-crazy-diamond');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
$(".block").each(function( index ) {
  $(this).hover(function(){
  $('body').append('<div class="fade"></div>');
  $(this).css({'z-index': '100'});
}, function(){
  $('.fade').remove();
  $(this).css({'z-index': ''});
});
});
```

```css
.block {
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px #555;
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

.fade {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">
  <div class="text">Какой-то текст</div>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <div class="text">Какой-то текст</div>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <div class="text">Какой-то текст</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

После нажатия на кнопку при наведении на блок эффект убирается.

```js
$("#button").click(function() {
  $('div:eq(2)').addClass('light');
  $('div:not(.light)').addClass('dark');
});
```

```css
.normal {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid;
  background-color: #51b8f3;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
}

.dark:after {
  content: '\A';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  opacity: 0.8;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

.light:after {
  content: '\A';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  opacity: 0.8;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

.light:hover:after,
.dark:hover:after {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="normal">Первый</div>
<div class="normal">Второй</div>
<div class="normal">Третий</div>
<div class="normal">Четверты</div>
<br />
<button id="button">Выделить третий блок</button>
```